# Tipagem dinâmica e o desenvolvimento em equipe

Tags: python, python-3.x, engenharia-de-software, estilo-de-codificação

Existe alguma boa prática, padronização, recomendação, etc. que vise evitar que sejam passados tipos inválidos para métodos e funções?

Se eu estiver trabalhando sozinho é mais tranquilo, eu mesmo escrevi o método por tanto eu sei quais os tipos dos parâmetros que ele espera receber, mas eu vejo um problema quando o desenvolvimento passa a ser em equipe. Como um terceiro vai saber se para um determinado método ele deve passar um inteiro ou uma strings, se deve ser uma lista, ou um outro objeto qualquer? Só em tempo de execução?

O único artifício que eu vejo é fazer uso massivo de *docstrings* e usar um editor com recurso de exibir a *docstring* ao escrever uma chamada a um método.

Alguma outra alternativa além desta?

Comment: Possivelmente, [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sou o mais adequado para falar pra Python.

Tens razão de entender que em equipe é mais complicado trabalhar com tipagem dinâmica. Pior ainda se o projeto é pequeno e dá para desenvolver sozinho, mas não há estabilidade de quem fará isto. A solução real é usar uma linguagem de tipagem estática, pode até ser o [MyPy](http://mypy-lang.org/) (não que eu esteja recomendando). Apesar de ser essencialmente Python considero outra linguagem porque há mudança semântica.

Documentar é a solução óbvia.

Usar uma ferramenta extra de análise estática é outra mais garantida. Isso deixa o código mais robusto, mas não tem ganho de performance. E vai ter que usar algo extra para fazer o projeto, é possível que tenha que criar a ferramenta, ou seja, melhor usar outra linguagem.

Outra estratégia legal, e muita gente usa, é criar testes que funcionam como analisadores estáticos. Em linguagens dinâmicas dá muito mais trabalho fazer certas verificações. E muito mais trabalho de escrever testes porque muito erro pode ocorrer enquanto que em linguagem estática seria garantido não ocorrer.

Em alguns casos é possível testar de [forma assertiva](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assert), que é meio que um teste *inline*.

Comment: Vendo o site o MyPy vi que ele se fundamenta na [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). A documentação da PEP fala que tal sintaxe está relacionado ao uso de annotations. Não aprofundei a leitura mas vi que quando faço uso dessa sintaxe `def greeting(name: str) -> str:` O intellisense do VSCode mostra o tipo do parâmetro.
Acho que a saída mais prática é realmente documentar o código.