# Quais ganhos eu tenho em especificar o tipo do argumento de uma função?

Tags: python, python-3.x, característica-linguagem, tipagem

Agora em é possível definir o [tipo do argumento](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing) que uma função ira receber.

Veja este pequeno exemplo de ilustração:

```
def soma1(v1: int, v2: int):
    return v1 + v2

def soma2(v1, v2):
    return v1 + v2

print(soma1(1, 2))
print(soma2(5, 2))
```

Ambas as funções fazem as mesmas coisas, porém o argumento de uma delas é tipado para inteiro `int`.

Essa característica do Python eu desconhecia até então, e me gerou algumas dúvidas.

## Dúvidas

1. Quais ganhos eu tenho em especificar o tipo do argumento de uma
   função?
2. Quando eu especifico o tipo do argumento o Python trata ele
   internamento sem a necessidade de fazer uma validação?
3. Isto também funciona para classes?

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicada: [Python 3: Tipos de Atributos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220637/5878)

Comment: (1) Alguma espécie de tipagem que não seja totalmente de pato? Tem quem considere a tipagem se pato um problema, então para sanar os seus problemas seria definir o tipo do argumento

Comment: Relacionada: [Tipagem dinâmica e o desenvolvimento em equipe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/305285/5878)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não havia percebido esta pergunta, a minha eh dup dela, a resposta aborda tudo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Quais ganhos eu tenho em especificar o tipo do argumento de uma função?

Em Python basicamente é a robustez, o compilador poderia impedir você chamar essa função com tipos errados (mas isto não está implementado, então só com ferramentas externas serve para alguma coisa, o que limita o seu uso). Sem isso, ou você testa dentro com código (um possível `if` ou abstração disso), ou faz muito teste de unidade, ou você confia e reza. Não há ganhos de performance, mas é possível que no futuro alguém crie certas otimizações, mas é complicado na implementação padrão. Python tem implementações alternativas que já tinha tipagem explícita com ganho de performance, mas não aí ela não é opcional.

> Quando eu especifico o tipo do argumento o Python trata ele internamento sem a necessidade de fazer uma validação?

Você faz isso no [parâmetro e não no argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101), e sim, uma ferramenta externa pode validar pra você. O argumento sempre teve tipo, ainda que implícito.

> Isto também funciona para classes?

Até onde eu sei, não, até porque classes não recebem valores, apenas métodos delas, mas se quer saber se é aceito em métodos (não só parâmetros), sim, é aceito. Na verdade as classes e métodos agora aceitam até um certo ponto *generics* (e pode usar na herança da classe). Sim, Python foi totalmente para a tipagem estática (opcional) :D Como eu sempre disse, é o futuro. Claro, não que ela obrigue a tipagem ou faça ser certa, mas deixa você fazer isso com algo externo se desejar, pelo menos tem uma sintaxe simples e óbvia pra lidar com isso, o que já é um passo ter a anotação.

Pode ler mais sobre na [PEP do Type Hint](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). E veja [MyPy](http://www.mypy-lang.org/).

E acabo de saber que a anotação permite quase qualquer coisa, o que só não classificarei de atrocidade, porque pode dar um flexibilidade interessante no futuro, mas também enormes problemas.

## *Duck Typing*

Complementando os comentários, isso nada tem a ver com [*duck typing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/574146/101), nem mesmo em oposição. A tipagem do pato (nome ruim também) indica algo próximo a [tipagem estrutural](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101) (não é a mesma coisa, apenas parece um pouco do lado da tipagem estática). Na verdade estamos falando de tipagem não manifesta, nem tem a ver com ser dinâmica, ela também é dinâmica, mas esta é outra característica. Eu entendo a confusão entre esses termos, por isso o *link* pode ajudar. Mas [o termo é até contestado por muitos](https://ericlippert.com/2014/01/02/what-is-duck-typing/). O seu significado não é claro e na verdade provavelmente fala de algo que já tinha um termo mais adequado, mas como é engraçadinho pegou.

Comment: Errado: "o compilador impede você chamar esta função com tipos errados". O interpretador ignora por completo a anotação de tipo. Se a função é anotada com inteiros e é passada uma *string*, ainda receberá como parâmetro *string*.

Comment: Errado: "o compilador valida pra você", também não, vide acima.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss estava lendo a PEP agora e realmente isto não foi implmentado

Comment: E, para completar, qualquer expressão válida é permitida como anotação: `def foo(var: 1+2+3)`, em que `inspect.signature(foo)` retornaria `(var:6)`. Nem sempre pode fazer sentido, mas quem sabe um dia alguém ache utilização para uma anotação desse gênero.